# Why does the location of my string declaration affect whether my html encoded entities will be displayed properly?

Tags: javascript

In adding a new feature to a web app, I need to dynamically set the value of a Button object.  It happens that I need to put some html-encoded unicode characters in the value.  In implementing this I found that the location in which I define the characters determines whether or not they are displayed properly.  If I define the character in the onclick event itself, they character is displayed properly.  If I define it in a function or at the top level, it is displayed as literal text.

I have distilled my issue into the following sample HTML/JS (note that my ultimate issue is unicode characters but I'm using lt/gt as examples):

```
<html><body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tlabel3 = '&gt; foo &lt;';
    function ChangeName2() {
        document.getElementById('button2').value = '&gt; foo &lt;';
    }
    function ChangeName3() {
        document.getElementById('button3').value = tlabel3;
    }
    function ChangeName4(label4) {
        document.getElementById('button4').value = label4;
    }
</script>
<input type=button id=button1 value="&lt; foo &gt;"> - <a href=# onclick="document.getElementById('button1').value = '&gt; foo &lt;'">Clicky</a>
<HR>
<input type=button id=button2 value="&lt; foo &gt;"> - <a href=# onclick="ChangeName2()">Clicky</a>
<HR>
<input type=button id=button3 value="&lt; foo &gt;"> - <a href=# onclick="ChangeName3()">Clicky</a>
<HR>
<input type=button id=button4 value="&lt; foo &gt;"> - <a href=# onclick="ChangeName4('&gt; foo &lt;')">Clicky</a>
</body></html>
```

In my tests in IE8, Safari, Chrome, and FF3.6, this behaves the same - Buttons 1 and 4, which have the characters defined in the onclick handler, work properly.  Buttons 2 and 3, having the characters defined elsewhere, display the literal `&gt;` string.

My question is, why does the location of the string definition matter?  I have a work around, but because all four browsers work the same way I feel like I'm missing knowledge some fundamental working of Javascript.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using things like &gt; and &lt; at the HTML level, they are rendered there, so they become > and <.
At javascript level, its just a string, and it isn't rendered as HTML(its javascript).

You can see what happens by changing the first button code to:

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('button1').value = '&gt; foo &lt;'">Clicky</a>
```

That way, when you hover the link and check your browser status bar, you will see the > and < symbols, instead of &gt; and &lt;. That means that the browser already rendered it, because it is inside the HTML code.

To obtain the same results as javascript, the correct would be to do &amp;gt;
Or just put the > < at javascript.

Comment: Crap.  I knew it would be obvious.  I actually saw the rendered/unrendered thing you mentioned in firebug, I just didn't take the meaning.

Comment: For bonus points, is there a render() or similar function that can be called from javascript to turn '&lt;' into <?

Comment: Hey @jj33, I don't know if theres a native function that does that. But there is a kind famous lib that does this here: http://www.strictly-software.com/htmlencode
There is a html_decode() function there, just what you need I think